# How does BindingExtension know its effective binding context?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, binding, markup-extensions

Just as `Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.BindingExtension` does its magic to get the effective binding context in order to return the `BindingBase` object that corresponds to the relevant source/path/mode, I would like to create an extension that does its voodoo based on the effective binding context as well. Through `IProvideValueTarget`, I managed to get the `BindingContext`, however, not the EFFECTIVE binding context, thus, when used in a `DataTemplate`, it always brings me the effective binding context of the parent rather than the `DataTemplate`. I am trying to find the effective binding context inside the data template.

In order for this to be clearer, I re-created the problem in a simple PoC.

We have the following model:

```
namespace App1.Models
{
    public class MyBeautifulModel
    {
        public string SomeData { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return SomeData;
        }
    }
}
```

The following view-model:

```
using App1.Models;

using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace App1.ViewModels
{
    public class MainPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public MainPageViewModel()
        {
            MyBeautifulModels = new[]
            {
                new MyBeautifulModel() { SomeData = "DataTemplate Data0" },
                new MyBeautifulModel() { SomeData = "DataTemplate Data1" },
                new MyBeautifulModel() { SomeData = "DataTemplate Data2" },
            };

            MyProperty = "Outer Template Data";
        }

        public IEnumerable<MyBeautifulModel> MyBeautifulModels { get; }

        public string MyProperty { get; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return MyProperty;
        }
    }
}
```

The following markup extension:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Internals;

namespace App1.MarkupExtensions
{
    public class PrintContextExtension : IMarkupExtension
    {
        public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            if (serviceProvider.GetService<IProvideValueTarget>() is SimpleValueTargetProvider provider)
            {
                object[] objectAndParents = (object[])typeof(SimpleValueTargetProvider).GetField("objectAndParents", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(provider);

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.AppendLine("Object and all its parents:");
                foreach (object obj in objectAndParents)
                    sb.AppendLine(obj.ToString());

                sb.AppendLine("First object with binding context:");
                BindableObject bindable = (BindableObject)objectAndParents.First(b => b is BindableObject bindableObject && bindableObject.BindingContext != null);
                sb.AppendLine(bindable.ToString());

                sb.AppendLine("The binding context of that object:");
                sb.AppendLine(bindable.BindingContext.ToString());
                string result = sb.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(result);
                return bindable.BindingContext.ToString();
            }
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
}
```

And the following view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:App1.ViewModels"
             xmlns:ext="clr-namespace:App1.MarkupExtensions"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="App1.Views.MainPage"
             Padding="20">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:MainPageViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Title"/>
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="LightGreen"/>
        </Style>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label>
                <Label.FormattedText>
                    <FormattedString>
                        <Span Text="Built-in Binding: "/>
                        <Span Text="{Binding MyProperty}"/>
                    </FormattedString>
                </Label.FormattedText>
            </Label>
            <Label>
                <Label.FormattedText>
                    <FormattedString>
                        <Span Text="My Binding: "/>
                        <Span Text="{ext:PrintContext MyProperty}"/>
                    </FormattedString>
                </Label.FormattedText>
            </Label>
            <Frame BorderColor="DimGray"
                   CornerRadius="15">
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyBeautifulModels}"
                      HasUnevenRows="True">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <StackLayout Margin="0,0,0,20">
                                    <Label>
                                        <Label.FormattedText>
                                            <FormattedString>
                                                <Span Text="Built-in Binding: "/>
                                                <Span Text="{Binding SomeData}"/>
                                            </FormattedString>
                                        </Label.FormattedText>
                                    </Label>
                                    <Label BackgroundColor="PaleVioletRed">
                                        <Label.FormattedText>
                                            <FormattedString>
                                                <Span Text="My Binding: "/>
                                                <Span Text="{ext:PrintContext SomeData}"/>
                                            </FormattedString>
                                        </Label.FormattedText>
                                    </Label>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </Frame>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Running this results in the following console output:

```
Object and all its parents:
Xamarin.Forms.Span
My Binding: 
Xamarin.Forms.Label
Xamarin.Forms.StackLayout
Xamarin.Forms.ViewCell
Xamarin.Forms.DataTemplate
Xamarin.Forms.ListView
Xamarin.Forms.Frame
Xamarin.Forms.StackLayout
App1.Views.MainPage
First object with binding context:
Xamarin.Forms.ListView
The binding context of that object:
Outer Template Data
```

And finally, this is how the view looks like in the runtime:
[image: runtime screenshot]

Sorry if the question looks too long but I hope my reproduce steps would make it easier to simplify and illustrate the problem.

p.s looking at [`BindingExtension`'s implementation on GitHub](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/main/Xamarin.Forms.Xaml/MarkupExtensions/BindingExtension.cs), it looks like `IServiceProvider` is not even used. That seems to be weird to me - as how does it know its context like that!

Comment: Please see`[ContentProperty(nameof(Path))]` above BindingExtension,  XAML processor uses to determine the content property.   `IServiceProvider` For internal use by the XAML infrastructure(So you do not see where is used).Your object has a BindingContext set in XAML. And without a BindingContext, there's no way to resolve them.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT ContentProperty - as you said - determines the content property, meaning, if you wrote `SomePropertyOnXaml="{Binding SomeContextProperty}"`, the value `"SomeContextProperty"` will be set in `BindingExtension.Path` property. The former clause is equivalent to `SomePropertyOnXaml="{Binding Path=SomeContextProperty}`. If there's no `Source` set explicitly in `BindingExtension`, the binding context is used. Here comes the question, how does it know the binding context.